# How do I view an app running in Heroku's staging environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, staging

When I push my app to the staging environment do I get a different main URL?

I inherited an app someone else built and deployed on Heroku. I'd like to test some
drastic changes that current users won't run into. It looks fine on my local machine,
but the app has some quirks that keep it from running on my own nginx/passenger-based
server. So Heroku it is.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku apps don't inherently have a staging environment. It's likely pushing to a second Heroku app the original developer was using as a staging environment. Read more about managing multiple environments on Heroku here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments